# Passing function in object between components through service

Tags: javascript, angular

Is possible to share function in object between components through service?

I have one component that push object to service and second one, which takes this object and renders it. Unfortunatelly, function in object seems empty.

Here's my approach so far:

First component:

```
bar:Object = {
  side: true,
  actions1: [
    {
      icon: 'arrow_back',
      label: '',
      action() {this.router.navigate(['/']);}
    },
    {
      icon: 'filter_list',
      label: '',
      action: ''
    },
    {
      icon: 'sync_alt',
      label: '',
      action: ''
    }
  ],
  actions2: []
}
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.add(this.bar);
}
```

Service:

```
  loadButtons = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  add(buttons) {
    this.loadButtons.emit(buttons);
  }
```

Second component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.loadButtons.subscribe( (buttons) => {
      this.buttons = buttons;    
    });
}
```

And I tried to render it this way:

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="this[button.action]()">
    <span>{{button.icon}}</span>
</button>
```

Since first step when I call log in console, object returns this value:

```
actions1: 
Array(3)
0: 
action:ƒ action()
length:0
name:"action"
arguments: 
[wyjątek: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:3:28)]
caller: 
[wyjątek: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:3:28)]
[[FunctionLocation]]: 
missing.component.ts:41
[[Prototype]]:ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]:Scopes[3]
icon:"arrow_back"
label: ""
[[Prototype]]:Object
```

What am I doing wrong?:)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?